Sensor Synchronization, IMU and Bundle Adjustment
Sensor synchronization is a general issue with SLAM systems, the ideal is having an IMU hardware synchronized with cameras.
There are a couple other possible variations though. One variation is assuming IMU and Camera information is not synchronized but a global timestamp exists for both. I'm wondering what the correct approach is under these circumstances?
The two ways I see are 1. Integrate the IMU data to the closest HW timestamp and 2. Split up the IMU period into two parts, integrate the IMU up until the Camera timestamp, add the camera factor, then integrate the rest of the IMU.
